# An explanation for a diagram.

Tags: geometry, proof-explanation

This was part of the solution of a question.

[image]

But the part of the explanation says that:

[image]

I don't understand how it works. Could anyone explain why $AC={CP\cdot QU \over UP}$ ?

I think I can carry it on once I understand this.

---

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint: Similar triangle. Try to show
\begin{align}
\Delta PQU \sim \Delta PAC.
\end{align}

Comment: Is it still similar even though $\triangle PQU$'s hypotenuse is the part of triangle's height, and hypotenuse of $\triangle PAC$ is the slant of the triangle?

Comment: Look carefully at the correspondence. $A$ is corresponding to $Q$.

Comment: ${AC \over CP} = {QU \over UP}$. I mean is it still similar even if their hypotenuses are not on the same line?

Comment: I don't quite understand what you mean.